# Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, patch

I am new to k8s and need some help, plz.

I want to make a change in a pod's deployment configuration and change readOnlyRootFilesystem to false.

This is what I am trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work. Plz suggest what's wrong:

```sh
kubectl patch deployment eric-ran-rdm-singlepod -n vdu -o yaml -p {"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"eric-ran-rdm-infra":{"securityContext":[{"readOnlyRootFilesystem":"true"}]}}]}}}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEIYl.png)

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Try adding single quote `'{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"eric-ran-rdm-infra":{"securityContext":[{"readOnlyRootFilesystem":"true"}]}}]}}}}'` around the patch.

Comment: You can also update the YAML file and then use `kubectl apply -f <your file>.yaml`. It will automatically generate and apply the patch.

Comment: You are not supplying valid JSON. Use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to check your JSON.

Answer (score 5):

In windows, you need to add before double quote in the command with a backslash.

```
kubectl patch cronjob/zoo-pc-route-cost-job -p '{\"spec\": {\"suspend\": false}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. You need to make sure you are providing valid JSON and it should be in the correct structure as defined by the k8s API as well. You can use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com).

```json
{
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "eric-ran-rdm-infra",
                        "securityContext": {
                            "readOnlyRootFilesystem": "true"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: I have only checked the syntax here and **not** checked/ tested the structure against the k8s API of this JSON here, but I think it should be right, please correct me if I am wrong.

It might be easier to specify a deployment in a `.yaml` file and just apply that using `kubectl apply -f my_deployment.yaml`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should fix your **JSON syntax issue** as suggested by **@Mushroomator**

```
{
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "eric-ran-rdm-infra",
                        "securityContext": {
                            "readOnlyRootFilesystem": "true"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, **JSON** should also be specified with escape char before double quotes.

Following this way:

```
kubectl patch deployment eric-ran-rdm-singlepod -n vdu -o yaml -p {\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"name\": \"eric-ran-rdm-infra\",\"securityContext\":{\"readOnlyRootFilesystem\":\"true\"}}]}}}}
```